# Rationale behind Ada encapsulation of dynamically dispatching operations (primitives)

Tags: ada, dynamic-dispatch

In Ada, [Primitive operations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Object_Orientation#Primitive_operations) of a type T can only be defined in the package where T is defined. For example, if a `Vehicules` package defines `Car` and `Bike` tagged record, both inheriting a common `Vehicle` abstract tagged type, then all operations than can dispatch on the class-wide `Vehicle'Class` type must be defined in this `Vehicles` package.

Let's say that you do not want to add primitive operations: you do not have the permission to edit the source file, or you do not want to clutter the package with unrelated features.

Then, you cannot define operations in *other* packages that implicitely dispatches on type `Vehicle'Class`.
For example, you may want to serialize vehicles (define a `Vehicles_XML` package with a `To_Xml` dispatching function) or display them as UI elements (define a `Vehicles_GTK` package with `Get_Label`, `Get_Icon`, ... dispatching functions), etc.
The only way to perform dynamic dispatch is to write the code explicitely; for example, inside `Vechicle_XML`:

```
if V in Car'Class then
   return Car_XML (Car (V));
else
   if V in Bike'Class then
      return Bike_XML (Bike (V));
   else
      raise Constraint_Error 
         with "Vehicle_XML is only defined for Car and Bike."
end if;
```

(And a Visitor pattern defined in `Vehicles` and used elsewhere would work, of course, but that still requires the same kind of explicit dispatching code. *edit* in fact, no, but there is still some boilerplate code to write)

My question is then:

**is there a reason why operations dynamically dispatching on T are restricted to be defined in the defining package of T?**

Is this intentional? Is there some historical reasons behind this?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the current answers: basically, it seems that it is a matter of language implementation (freezing rules/virtual tables).

I agree that compilers are developped incrementally over time and that not all features fit nicely in an existing tool.
As such, isolating dispatching operators in a unique package seems to be a decision mostly guided by existing implementations than by language design. Other languages outside of the C++/Java family provide dynamic dispatch without such requirement (e.g. OCaml, Lisp (CLOS);  if that matters, those are also *compiled* languages, or more precisely, language for which compilers exist).

When I asked this question, I wanted to know if there were more fundamental reasons, at language specification level, behind this part of Ada specifications (otherwise, does it really mean that the *specification* assumes/enforces a particular implementation of dynamic disapatch?)

Ideally, I am looking for an authoritative source, like a *rationale* or *guideline* section in Reference Manuals, or any kind of archived discussion about this specific part of the language.

Comment: I would inquire about the possibility of adding a Visitor pattern using Ada-2005 Interfaces instead of requiring more primitive operations in the classes themselves. This is not an answer but hopefully it will inspire one (or a coherent reason why it can't work!) from someone more experienced in using interfaces.

Comment: @brian The Visitor pattern is a good workaround: (i) define a visitor interface in `Vehicles` (ii) defines the `Visit` procedures that dispatch on vehicle types and takes a visitor `v` as a second argument; each procedure calls `v.Visit_XXX` (where `XXX` varies for each known derived type) and (iii) implement derived visitor types in other packages (`Vehicle_XML_Visitor`, ...). I think I don't enjoy writing visitor patterns again and again, though :-)

Comment: I was looking for ways to write it *once* as an Interface and *use* it again and again. The nearest I can come up with is for the instantiation to include Vehicle as a record component. Ugly but might get the job done. I think a short "Introduction to the best ways to implement GoF Design Patterns it Ada 2005/2012" would be useful...

Comment: @brian Honestly, I don't see how to achieve it (even with generic packages), because a Visitor typically must define `Visit_XXX` functions that depends on the actual type being visited. How would you use the record component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of several reasons:

(1) Your example has `Car` and `Bike` defined in the same package, both derived from `Vehicles`.  However, that's not the "normal" use case, in my experience; it's more common to define each derived type in its own package.  (Which I think is close to how "classes" are used in other compiled languages.)  And note also that it's not uncommon to define new derived types *afterwards*.  That's one of the whole points of object-oriented programming, to facilitate reuse; and it's a good thing if, when designing a new feature, you can find some existing type that you can derive from, and reuse its features.

So suppose you have your `Vehicles` package that defines `Vehicle`, `Car`, and `Bike`.  Now in some other package `V2`, you want to define a new dispatching operation on a `Vehicle`.  For this to work, you have to provide the overriding operations for `Car` and `Bike`, with their bodies; and assuming you are not allowed to modify `Vehicles`, then the language designers have to decide where the bodies of the new operation have to be.  Presumably, you'd have to write them in `V2`.  (One consequence is that the body that you write in `V2` would not have access to the private part of `Vehicles`, and therefore it couldn't access implementation details of `Car` or `Bike`; so you could only write the body of that operation if terms of already-defined operations.)  So then the question is: does `V2` need to provide operations for **all** types that are derived from `Vehicle`?  What about types derived from `Vehicle` that don't become part of the final program (maybe they're derived to be used in someone else's project)?  What about types derived from `Vehicle` that haven't yet been defined (see preceding paragraph)?  In theory, I suppose this could be made to work by checking everything at link time.  However, that would be a **major** paradigm change for the language.  It's not something that could be easily.  (It's pretty common, by the way, for programmers to think "it would be nice to add feature X to a language, and it shouldn't be too hard because X is simple to talk about", without realizing just what a vast impact such a "simple" feature would have.)

(2) A practical reason has to do with how dispatching is implemented.  Typically, it's done with a vector of procedure/function pointers.  (I don't know for sure what the exact implementation is in all cases, but I think this is basically the case for every Ada compiler as well as for C++ and Java compilers, and probably C#.)  What this means is that when you define a tagged type (or a class, in other languages), the compiler will set up a vector of pointers, and based on how many operations are defined for the type, say N, it will reserve slots 1..N in the vector for the addresses of the subprograms.  If a type is derived from that type and defines overriding subprograms, the derived type gets its own vector, where slots 1..N will be pointers to the actual overriding subprograms.  Then, when calling a dispatching subprogram, a program can look up the address in some known slot index assigned to that subprogram, and it will jump to the correct address depending on the object's actual type.  If a derived type defines *new* primitive subprograms, new slots are assigned N+1..N<sub>2</sub>, and types derived from that could define new subprograms that get slots N<sub>2</sub>+1..N<sub>3</sub>, and so on.

Adding new dispatching subprograms to `Vehicle` would interfere with this.  Since new types have been derived from `Vehicle`, you can't insert a new area into the vector after N, because code has already been generated that assumes the slots starting at N+1 have been assigned to new operations derived for derived types.  And since we may not know all the types that have been derived from `Vehicle` and we don't know what other types will be derived from `Vehicle` in the future and how many new operations will be defined for them, it's hard to pick some other location in the vector that could be used for the new operations.  Again, this could be done if all of the slot assignment were deferred until link time, but that would be a major paradigm change, again.

To be honest, I can think of other ways to make this work, by adding new operations not in the "main" dispatch vector but in an auxiliary one; dispatching would probably require a search for the correct vector (perhaps using an ID assigned to the package that defines the new operations).  Also, adding `interface` types to Ada 2005 has already complicated the simple vector implementation somewhat.  But I do think this (i.e. it doesn't fit into the model) is one reason why the ability to add new dispatching operations like you suggest isn't present in Ada (or in any other *compiled* language that I know of).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Regardin visibility in (1): using multiple packages surely is a good
practice, but I think visibility of private part is an orthogonal
issue: ideally, visitors should operate on data types through the
public API exposed by the package (a visitor that needs to access
private parts can be defined in the original package or a child
package, with some limitations).
As for derived types (still in (1)), this would not be a problem:
     inheritance tells us that the most specialized operation defined in V2 that matches the argument at runtime shall be picked. (...)

Comment: (...) In fact, this is exactly what the above explicit dispatch does: if there is an object of a (new) type Electric_Car (derived from Car), the current function will end up calling Car_XML, because an Electric_Car is a Car. The question is: why sould we write the
     dispatching code ourselves instead of letting the compiler
     generate it?
Finally, in (2), what you say essentially is that is mostly due to technical choices in tools, not necessarly a choice at language specification level. I agree that this is most likely to be  the actual reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Without having checked the rationale for Ada 95 (where tagged types were introduced), I am pretty sure the freezing rules for tagged types are derived from the simple requirement that all objects in T'Class should have all the dispatching operations of type T.

To fulfill that requirement, you have to freeze type and say that no more dispatching operations can be added to type T once you:

- Derive a type from T, or
- Are at the end of the package specification where T was declared.

If you didn't do that, you could have a type derived from type T (i.e. in T'Class), which hadn't inherited all the dispatching operations of type T.  If you passed an object of that type as a T'Class parameter to a subprogram, which knew of one more dispatching operation on type T, a call to that operation would have to fail. - We wouldn't want that to happen.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. Still, what you said is true because we assume files are compiled separately and then linked together blindly. A compiler/linker could perform "one more pass" over data types to compute all dispatching operations for all types. Don't get me wrong, the amout of work that was, and still is done, in the development of Ada compilers is impressive: I am not saying that they are "wrong" or "bad".

Comment: Doing that would mean that the layout of a type would be different depending on which **other** packages are compiled into an application.  That is bad style, and it could mean that with'ing an extra package at one place in an application would introduce a compilation error at a completely different place.  You **DON'T** want that.

Comment: What about cyclic elaboration errors, then? application-level errors exist and can occur when using conflicting packages together, and if this happens, I am happy to see compile/link errors. I agree that this could be bad style, but again, the alternatives (explicit dispatch and/or visitor pattern) bring safety and style issues as well.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your extended question:

Ada comes with both a **Reference Manual** (the ISO standard), a **Rationale** and an **Annotated Reference Manual**.  And a large part of the discussions behind these documents are public as well.

For Ada 2012 see http://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/standards/ada12/

Tagged types (dynamic dispatching) was introduced in Ada 95.  The documents related to that version of the standard can be found at http://www.adaic.org/ada-resources/standards/ada-95-documents/

Comment: Thanks. Section 4.3, Part 2 of Ada95 Rationale should be what I am looking for and describe an implementation model based on jump tables; also: "we emphasize that this is just a
possible model and does not imply that an implementation has to be done this way.  In this model the tag is a pointer to a dispatch table. [...]". I'll continue reading this.